# Knoppix multiple desktops

Tags: compiz, workspaces

I have knoppix 6.4.4 installed on a persistent usb drive. By default, compiz is set up and allows me to switch between my four desktops. The problem is, when I have two browsers open, one in desktop1 and one in desktop2, they both show it the taskbar in both desktops. I would like to keep them separate, each desktop showing only its current windows. This is how ubuntu sets up workspaces by default, but after much searching, I could not find any such settings on knoppix.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the settings by right clicking on the bottom pannel.
If I remember; there is a check box that says something like "keep windows on their own desktop" or something to that effect.

Comment: When I right click and click on panel settings, I don't see any settings like that.

Comment: When I right click and goto `"Taskbar (window list)" Settings` there is an option called `Show windows from all desktops`. From the way my panels are acting, you would think that it would be checked already, buts its not. Also, checking and un-checking it does not seem to change anything.